# Create Table and Insert using stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'am trying to create a procedure checking table and insert 
but it show me some error which i'am not sure how to fix it

this is the error code

> Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or
>   trigger

```
 DELIMITER ;;
   CREATE FUNCTION `getLabel`(paradocid INT, paradoctype    char(10),paradoclineid INT,paraqty INT,paracreated date,paracreatedby   INT) RETURNS int(100)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE transtotal int;
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total int;



 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sim_lable`(
  `label_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `doctype` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `docid` int NOT NULL,
  `doclineid` int NOT NULL,
  `created` date NOT NULL,
  `createdby` int NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE='InnoDB' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';

DELETE FROM sim_lable where  
(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(paracreatedby,createdby))/60) >30;
SELECT @total=coalesce(count(*),0) as total2 from sim_label where 
doctype=paradoctype and paradocid=docid;
 IF total = 0 THEN
    WHILE i < paraqty DO
         INSERT INTO dbo.Students
          ( 
            `doctype` ,
            `docid`,
            `doclineid` ,
            `created` ,
            `createdby`
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            paradoctype,
            paradocid,
            paradoclineid,
            paracreated,
            paracreatedby
          ) ;
    END WHILE;
    END IF;
  END
```

Comment: you aren't creating a stored proc. You are starting to create a function, then just into a table create, etc. Confusing. A combination of like 3 things

Comment: You can create a table from a stored procedure but not from a stored function.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger. CREATE TABLE statement causes an [implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html), therefore it is not allowed in a function.

Your code does not seem to return any value (there is no return statement in the function's body) and what you are doing there should be done in a stored procedure, rather than in a function.